# Android.mk: Why does $(info) and $(warning) not reflect value of variables assigned from within functions?

Tags: makefile

Simple test code used in an `Android.mk` file:

```
my_var := 'Foo'
$(warning $(my_var))
```

Produces expected output:

```
jni/Android.mk:6: 'Foo'
```

---

However, when defining a function, and calling this, local variables seem to be ignored (as if the `warning` line was processed first). E.g:

```
define my_func
    my_var := 'Test $1'
    $(warning "MYFUNC: <$1> [$(my_var)]")
endef

$(call my_func,'foo')
$(call my_func,'bar')
```

Output:

```
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <'foo'> []"
jni/Android.mk:11: "MYFUNC: <'bar'> []"
```

---

If defining this `my_var` outside the function scope:

```
my_var := 'norf'
define my_func
    my_var := 'Test $1'
    $(warning "MYFUNC: <$1> [$(my_var)]")
endef

$(call my_func,'foo')
$(call my_func,'bar')
```

Output:

```
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <'foo'> ['norf']"
jni/Android.mk:11: "MYFUNC: <'bar'> ['norf']"
```

---

When used in a `foreach` loop, it behaves again as if it was the first line in the `my_func` function (in fact, having it as the first line gives the same output):

```
define my_func
    my_var := 'Test $1'
    $(warning "MYFUNC: <$1> [$(my_var)]")
endef

items := foo bar qux norf
$(foreach item,$(items),$(eval $(call my_func,$(item))))
```

Output:

```
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <foo> []"
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <bar> ['Test foo']"
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <qux> ['Test bar']"
jni/Android.mk:10: "MYFUNC: <norf> ['Test qux']"
```

---

If only inspecting values *after* function calls, it outputs expected values.
It is only from within functions that I found `warning` and `info` to behave unexpectedly.

---

Can someone explain this?

Using `$(info OUT)` instead of `$(warning OUT)` exhibits similar behavior. I haven't found either of these functions in the NDK docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation order for define rules is quite tricky to get right, in this case, the issue is that the warning is evaluated too early, and that the variable assignment might not get evaluated at all.

By modifying your example like this, I got it working:

```
define my_func
    my_var := 'Test $1'
    $$(warning "MYFUNC: <$1> [$$(my_var)]")
endef

$(eval $(call my_func,'foo'))
$(eval $(call my_func,'bar'))
```

By using $$ for the use of the variable and for the warning, the evaluation of them get postponed until the wrapping $(eval) call that I added, which then happens after the variable has been assigned.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154557 for some more hints and explanations on the subject.